# Tcl: Special characters in 'exec' command

Tags: tcl

Here's an Imagemagick command for retrieving pixel values from an image foo.tiff:

```
convert foo.tiff [1x1+40+30] -format %[fx:int(65535*r)],%[fx:int(65535*g)],%[fx:int(65535*b)] info:-
```

How do I format this to make it acceptable to the Tcl 'exec' command? I've tried a variety of escaping the various characters, enclosing in braces, and so on. I appreciate the advice...

Answer (score 1):

Tcl will do the right thing if you split that string into a list:

```
set cmd {convert foo.tiff [1x1+40+30] -format %[fx:int(65535*r)],%[fx:int(65535*g)],%[fx:int(65535*b)] info:-}
exec {*}[split $cmd]
```

Comment: That string is actually a well-formed list already. `exec {*}$cmd` would work.

Comment: That works! But what is this {*} thing? That's totally new to me...Thanks for the help.

Comment: It is one of the very few syntax rules of Tcl: it expands a list into its elements. Suppose `set var [list foo bar baz]`. When you call `acommand $var` then "acommand" receives only one argument, the list {foo bar baz}. When you call `acommand {*}$var` then "acommand" receives *three* arguments, the strings "foo", "bar" and "baz". See http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/Tcl.htm -- in Tcl 8.4 and earlier, we had to resort to `eval` to achieve the same effect.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I'd just quote the bits that must not be substituted with `{}`:

```
exec convert foo.tiff {[1x1+40+30]} -format {%[fx:int(65535*r)],%[fx:int(65535*g)],%[fx:int(65535*b)]} info:-
```